# Promise resolve even in case of error and trigger then next function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, promise, resolve

In some cases, 'getData' will throw an error, but I need to resolve it anyhow.
How do I resolve 'getData' and ensure 'updateInfo' is called even if 'getData' throws an error?

```
getData(this.props.data, {})
  .then(
    () => updateInfo('UPDATE_INFO', path, data)
  );
```

How do I fix this?

```
Promise.resolve(
  getData(this.props.data, {}))
    .then(
      () => updateInfo('UPDATE_INFO', path, data)
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of resolving the promise intentionally, if you wish to take an action on both error and success case, you can use `.finally` on Promise

```
getData(this.props.data, {}).finally(() => updateInfo('UPDATE_INFO', path, data));
```

Comment: with finally you need to use the `.then` and `.catch` also. as you will not be catching the error if there's any.

Comment: ok, How about rejecting the 'getData()' call in case it fails, and just call 'updateInfo'?

Comment: @Sunny then you just need `finally` block.

Comment: @AZ_ catch and then are needed only when you need to do success and error handling separately too. I don't think for the OP, there is a need to use .then and .catch too

Comment: I mean if getData() is fine, then make both getData() and updateInfo() calls, otherwise just make updateInfo() call. How should that be handled?

Answer (score 1):

One thing that's not immediately clear from your example is if `path` and `data` are returned by `getData()` or not, which changes the answer a bit.

If you want to execute the same callback regardless of whether the returned promise resolves or rejects (and you don't need to get `path` and `data` from `getData()`), you can use `Promise.prototype.finally()`:

```js
getData(this.props.data, {})
  .finally(() => updateInfo('UPDATE_INFO', path, data));
```

Alternatively, if you want to have different behavior depending on whether the promise resolves or rejects (i.e. `path` and `data` are returned by `getData()`), you can do something like:

```js
getData(this.props.data, {})
  .catch(e => /* handle error */) // If this callback doesn't throw an error or return a promise that rejects, it returns a resolved promise
  .then((path = null, data = {}) => updateInfo('UPDATE_INFO', path, data));
```

Comment: No, path and data are not returned by getData()

Comment: Then `Promise.prototype.finally()` is definitely what you want!

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do it would be with [Promise.finally()](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/promise/finally), but if you don't have that, you could trigger your next function in both the `then()` and `catch()` phase:

```
getData(this.props.data, {})
    .then(
        () => updateInfo('UPDATE_INFO', path, data)
    ).catch(
        () => updateInfo('UPDATE_INFO', path, data)
    );
```

Which you could refactor into:

```
const update = updateInfo.bind(null,'UPDATE_INFO', path, data);
getData(this.props.data, {})
    .then(update)
    .catch(update);
```

Or more simply:

```
const update = updateInfo.bind(null,'UPDATE_INFO', path, data);
getData(this.props.data, {}).then(update,update);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use finally either because of an older version of Node or not a bluebird promise.

`.then` accepts the second parameter for rejection of promise

```
getData(this.props.data, {})
    .then(
        () => updateInfo('UPDATE_INFO', path, data), (error) => updateInfo('UPDATE_INFO', path, data)
    );
```

Or implement the same code in `.catch` as well

```
getData(this.props.data, {})
    .then(
        () => updateInfo('UPDATE_INFO', path, data)
    ).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        return updateInfo('UPDATE_INFO', path, data)
    })
```